# Wijmo LineChart Live feed from SignalR, initial data points from JSON URL

Tags: json, signalr, wijmo

I have been struggling for a while with this. Too long. Hopefully soon somebody can help me with the code that allows me to do the following:

1. Over the course of a users session, we are creating dynamic LineCharts as a result of different actions occurring and then expiring.
2. These charts should open up with an initial number of data points of around 1000. Our plan was to pull this mostly static data (stock prices over the last few minutes) from a JSON query.
3. Following that initial load, as we receive pricing data for the asset being charted, we are using SignalR to transmit these non-periodic (IOW, constant polling isn’t useful) price changes to our chart.

All database triggers and the SignalR connection is in place. What we’re not getting is how to do that initial load, then change the data source to the SignalR feed.

What is further complicating things is that each dynamic chart has a different initial load, so using a shared data source is also an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Joey

Comment: Initial load is simply a json object which can be stored in a javascript array and once chart is populated with that you can then attach signalR source on its first data arrival and you can even count data-points arrived via signalR feed and remove or append to the existing array.